# Additive Roman Numeral 4

Tags: roman-numerals

I am working on a diplomatic edition of a 15th century book and it numbers its folios using the standard roman numerals of the time.  I've been using the following to get the page/folio in my header:

```
\newcommand{\rectoverso}[1]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{#1}}{r}{v}}
\newcommand{\folio}[1]{\the\numexpr (#1+1)/2\relax}
\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral \value{\folio{\thepage}}}\rectoverso{\thepage}
```

This works great, but the problem is that the roman numeral sequence is off of what I need.  Instead of **I**, **II**, **III**, ***IIII***, **V**, **VI**, **VII**, **VIII**, **IX**, **X**, I get the subtractive **IV** (somewhat understandably, given it's the far more common one in modern usage).  My source text only (and always) uses the additive *4* in the one's position: *24* is **XXIIII**, *34* is **XXXIIII** but *44* is **XLIIII**.  *9* is universally rendered subtractively as **IX** or **XC**.

Is there a package that allows for some control over which numbers are done additively and which are subtractively, or would my best option be to write my own custom definition to account for the specific style used in my book?

Comment: (and apologies if this is a rather simple / stupid question — this is the first time I'm using LaTeX, and somewhat out of necessity, because I'm scripting the creation of the document from my source files)

Comment: Is it only 4 which should be rendered `IIII` or must all cases of `IV` be eliminated?  In other words, is `XXIV` OK? or should it be `XXIIII`?  I'm asking because I notice that for 9 you've written `IX` which seems a bit inconsistent.

Comment: @A.Ellett only instances of *-4* are IIII (so *40* is *XL*), *9* is always subtractive (*IV* or *XC*).  Editing the question now.

Comment: Use of `\thepage` in calculations are discouraged, as it may not represent a number in general.

Comment: @Werner What is the preferred alternative for grabbing the number of the current page that would be guaranteed to represent a number?

Comment: @guifa: `\value{page}` would retrieve the value (number) of the `page` counter. However, even that is not reliable at times, the page shipout routine (which influences the `page` counter) is asynchronous. The best option is to set a `\label{<something>}` and then use [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount)'s `\getpagerefnumber{<something>}`. References are guaranteed to produce the correct page number, and `\getpagerefnumber` is expandable (so can be used in calculations).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a fully expandable version, so in your header or footer you just use `\thepage` and not complicated unexpandable constructions.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\rectoversoroman}{m}
 { % #1 is a counter name
  \guifa_rectoverso_roman:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \guifa_rectoverso_roman:n
 {
  \guifa_rectoverso_fix:f { \int_div_round:nn { \value{#1} } { 2 } } 
  \int_if_odd:nTF { \value{#1} } { r } { v }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \guifa_rectoverso_fix:n
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 10 } == 4 }
   {
    \int_to_Roman:n { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 10 } * 10 } IIII
   }
   {
    \int_to_Roman:n { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \guifa_rectoverso_fix:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\rectoversoroman{page}}

\newcounter{test}
\renewcommand{\thetest}{\rectoversoroman{test}}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_replicate:nn {250}
 {
  \stepcounter{test}\thetest\par
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\label{test}

This text is on page \pageref{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Just replace `IV` by `IIII`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \myRomannumeral { m }
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \int_to_Roman:n { #1 } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { IV } { IIII }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

4 \myRomannumeral{4}

14 \myRomannumeral{14}

44 \myRomannumeral{44}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 14):

If you don't mind loading `xparse`, here's a solution working with `expl3` code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\myRomannumeral{m}
  {
    \bool_if:nTF { \int_compare_p:n {#1 = 4} }
      {
        IIII
      }
      {
        \bool_if:nTF { \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn {#1} {10} = 4 } }
        {
          \int_to_Roman:n { \int_eval:n {#1/10*10} } IIII
        }
        {
          \int_to_Roman:n {#1}
        }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%% used solely for illustrative purposes.
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \myn in {1,...,30}
  {\myn $\rightarrow$ \myRomannumeral{\myn}\par}

\end{document}
```