# Change roman number four from IV to IIII in section (IEEEtran)

Tags: numbering, ieeetran

I want to change the numbering for a the fourth section in IEEEtran document from IV to IIII.

Is there a simple way to do it without setting a counter manually?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you doing that? I thought they stopped using IIII hundreds of years ago.

Comment: All my latin teachers in school were used to use the IIII "format" and I'll keep it also that way. However that should not be the point of this question.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate (it's not about the section numbering) but how to get iiii instead of iv: [Additive Roman Numeral 4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285378/82917).

Comment: thanks for that. but I am still not getting it completely done. I tried to override/renew the command `\thesection` to `\myRomannumeral{\Roman{section}}` which fails as if I am calling `\section` in my document `missing number, treated as zero`, `missing endcsname inserted` and `extra endcsname` occure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \myRomannumeral { m }
{
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \int_to_Roman:n { #1 } }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { IV } { IIII }
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

from [Additive Roman Numeral 4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285378/additive-roman-numeral-4)(thanks to [campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/82917/campa) linking it!) and added this line:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\myRomannumeral{\value{section}}}
```